# Ruby regex to remove all consecutive letters from string

Tags: ruby, regex

Here is the problem (from Codeforces)

Polycarp thinks about the meaning of life very often. He does this constantly, even when typing in the editor. Every time he starts brooding he can no longer fully concentrate and repeatedly presses the keys that need to be pressed only once. For example, instead of the phrase "how are you" he can type "hhoow aaaare yyoouu".

Polycarp decided to automate the process of correcting such errors. He decided to write a plug-in to the text editor that will remove pairs of identical consecutive letters (if there are any in the text). Of course, this is not exactly what Polycarp needs, but he's got to start from something!

Help Polycarp and write the main plug-in module. Your program should remove from a string all pairs of identical letters, which are consecutive. If after the removal there appear new pairs, the program should remove them as well. Technically, its work should be equivalent to the following: while the string contains a pair of consecutive identical letters, the pair should be deleted. Note that deleting of the consecutive identical letters can be done in any order, as any order leads to the same result.

Here is my solution..  For some reason it fails an extremely large test case.  Mine seems to get rid of more letters than it is supposed to.  Is this regular expression incorrect?

```
str = gets.chomp

while str =~ /(.)\1/
  str.gsub!(/(.)\1+/,'')
end

puts str
```

EDIT -- This solution doesn't work because it gets rid of all consecutive groups of characters.  It should only get rid of duplicates.  If I do it this way, which I believe to be correct, it times out on extremely large strings:

```
str = gets.chomp

while str =~ /(.)\1/
  str.gsub!(/(.)\1/,'')
end

puts str
```

Comment: Do you have to use a regular expression?  How about the squeeze method? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze

Comment: That looks good but it deletes only one of the duplicates.  I want to delete both duplicates.  So "aab" becomes "b"

Comment: But what should happen to `'aaab'`? Should that become `'ab'` or `'b'`?

Comment: What do you mean it times out?  You could refine it to only match valid characters like `/([a-z])\1/i`.

Answer (score 8):

Why does it have to be a regular expression?

```
'foobar'.squeeze
=> "fobar"

"hhoow aaaare yyoouu".squeeze
=> "how are you"
```

[`squeeze`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze) is a useful tool for compressing runs of all characters, or specific ones. Here are some examples from [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze):

```
"yellow moon".squeeze                  #=> "yelow mon"
"  now   is  the".squeeze(" ")         #=> " now is the"
"putters shoot balls".squeeze("m-z")   #=> "puters shot balls"
```

If "aab" becomes "b", then you're not following the example given in the question, which is "hhoow" turns into "how". By your statement it would be "w", and "yyoouu" would be "". I think you're reading too much into it and not understanding the problem based on their sample input and sample output.

Comment: This is what I suggested in the comments.  It's hard to say what exactly he wants.  I am trying to come up with a consecutive solution now.

Comment: No, the question is poorly formed.  The examples cited in the actual problem agree with what I'm saying.  Here is link http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/81/A

Answer (score 1):

ha, harder than I thought when I first read. What about

```
s = "hhoow aaaareer yyoouu"
while s.gsub!(/(.)\1+/, '')
end
puts s
```

which leaves `s == 'w'` if i understand the problem correctly.

Comment: I realized that doesn't work because you have strings such as "aaab" which will end up as "b" when the proper output is "ab"

Comment: @ordinary in your comments to your question, you say that "aab" becoming "b" is correct. I think your comment was mistaken.

Comment: Yes.  "aab" should become "b".  But "aaab" should become "ab".  This is because each *pair* of consecutive letters should be removed.

Comment: It is quite easy to make it output `ab`, though. Just do replacement with the text captured by 1st capturing group.

Comment: sorry i dont understand.  I'm new to regex

Comment: oh you mean replace with '\1'