# Regex: get the unique characters in one single word

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the unique characters while getting rid of the repeated characters.
Example:

```
aabbcddppppmmmzzdjjnnleeeerroitt
```

And I want to get:

```
cdloi
```

And ignore all the other letters (or characters) repeated twice or more than twice. Any idea?

I have been trying to get solutions with the likes of (.)(\1) but to no avail so far.
Thanks,

Comment: what should be the output of `aaca`?

Comment: @Lucius: `ca` - thanks.

Comment: Dupe of [Ruby regex to remove all consecutive letters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650302/ruby-regex-to-remove-all-consecutive-letters-from-string)

Comment: I see you've accepted the javascript solution.  Perhaps put a javascript tag on your question if that was the language you were looking for.

Comment: Not sure why `d` should be included in the output as it is repeated in the original string.

Comment: @myeong Please take a moment to clean up your question.  Your question is not only here to serve you and the answerers, this page becomes a timeless resource for future visitors.  If you will not make better sense of your question, then it may be flagged as unclear and closed and that seems unfortunate since it appears you have selected an answer.  Read Don'tPanic's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace all repetitive substrings from the string where the repetitive string can find out using [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with the [back reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

```
/(\w)\1+/g

// or for any character except newline

/(.)\1+/g
```

Demo with JS :

```js
console.log(
  'aabbcddppppmmmzzdjjnnleeeerroitt'
  .replace(/(.)\1+/g, '')
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll do what you just said, and replace the duplicated characters with nothing.